# prevent wrapping of content

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a layout with 2 listviews one on top of the other
their layout height is set to "wrap_content" and layout width ist "match_parent"
both have a layout weight of 50 (i.e. 50 percent)
if both listviews are empty, everything is fine, but when the upper listview contains many elements and the lower listview remains empty, the layout makes one list view grow and the other shrink.
i want both list views to never change their relative size in the layout and instead have scrolling!

Comment: yup we will just be guessing in the dark unless you upload the xml from your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the heights to wrap_content, set them to 0dip instead.